# Reading in strings from text file python

Tags: python

I am reading in words from a text file and comparing them to a set of words just to see how many times they appear in the sample document. For example, I have a text file and I want to see how many times the word "engineer" occurs.

The problem is that with my sample data, string comparison isn't working. I see that the program is indeed reading in what appears to be a word of `<type 'str'>` that looks like "engineer"; however, there is no match. When printing out the ASCII for each character in the word using `ord(character)`, there appear to be 0's in between each character. The output for the string "engineer" then looks like the following:

```
0 101 0 110 0 103 0 105 0 110 0 101 0 101 0 114 0
```

Using `strip()` removes the beginning and the end 0's, but not the middle ones. Any thoughts on what format these strings are in and how I can fix it?

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Sounds like UTF-16.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting 0's in between each character, but maybe you could split on them and reassemble your string without the 0s?

Comment: show your code and file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [UTF-16-BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding for the string `engineer`.<sup>1</sup>

UTF-16 uses two bytes for BMP characters (including ASCII characters), so, for example, the character `e`, which is Unicode (and ASCII) character number 101 (0x65 hex), shows up as the 16-bit code unit 101. In big-endian (that's what the `-BE` part means), the first byte is 0, and the second byte is 101. So, if your text is pure ASCII, your UTF-16 ends up looking like ASCII with an extra `\0` byte before each character.

---

The cleanest way to solve this is to open the file as a Unicode file. As a general rule, if you decode everything to `unicode` as part of reading it, encode back to bytes only at the very end as part of writing it, and do all the work in the middle with `unicode`, everything is simpler.

In Python 2.7, there are two ways to do this, [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) or [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open). Using `codecs` makes your code a bit easier to port to Python 2.5, using `io` makes it a bit easier to port to 3.x, but it doesn't make a difference otherwise in simple cases like this.

Notice that your `line` strings will now be `unicode` instead of `str`, so ideally you'll want your set of search strings to also be `unicode` values.

```
d = {u'engineer': 0, u'conductor': 0, u'transit cop': 0}
with io.open(path, encoding='utf-16-be') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            d[line.strip()] += 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

---

Another alternative is to read the file as binary UTF-16-BE, and make your search strings UTF-16-BE-encoded `str` values:

```
d = {u'engineer': 0, u'conductor': 0, u'transit cop': 0}
d = {key.encode('utf-16-be'): count for key, count in d.items()}
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            d[line.rstrip('\n\0')] += 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Notice that I had to be careful with stripping, to make sure to remove the whole two-byte `\0\n` at the end instead of just the `\n` byte, and to not strip off the `\0` byte at the start. This is just one of many ways that dealing with encoded bytes is more of a pain than dealing with Unicode. And if your final output is going to involve, say, printing these strings to your console or writing them out to a UTF-8 file, it'll get even more painful. If the final output is going to be another UTF-16-BE file, and if saving a bit of CPU is really important, it might be worth doing it this way. But otherwise, I'd go with the first.

---

<sub>1. Actually, you've got an extra `\0` at the end. But presumably in your real data, that's actually the first byte of the next character—maybe a `\n`, which, in UTF-16-BE, of course looks like `\0\n`.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a job for the regex library https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.  Match on a suitable regex to get the number of hits per line.  Add em all up to get the file level:

```
pattern = re.compile("engine")
len(pattern.findall("engine engineers love engineering"))
>>>
3
```